# Windows 10 pro, after anniversary update I can't use "runas administrator shortcut" anymore

Tags: windows-10, shortcuts, runas

Until now I used shortcut with `"runas/user:ComputerName\Administrator /savecred "C:\Program Files (x86)\example.exe"`

when I type a command in the cmd error 740 occurs:

```
C:\>"C:\Users\user\Favorites\Linki\runas.exe.lnk"
Attempting to start C:\Program Files (x86)\example.exe as user "ComputerName\Administrator" ...
RUNAS ERROR: Unable to run - C:\Program Files (x86)\example.exe
740: The requested operation requires elevation.
```

Does anyone know if this is an error or a deliberate action, and how I can achieve this functionality now?

Regards

Comment: Is your command prompt in admin/elevated mode?

Comment: @techturtle Yes it is. But shortcut is lunched from standard user and admin cred has to be typed once. /savecred should save it

Comment: FYI for people coming more recently - I just got bitten by this on a machine, now running Windows 10 version 1803 (as installed on 2018-06-18).  Solutions below worked.

Comment: Is there a reason you cant simply "right-click, run as admin"? Do you really need to run these apps under the actual Administrator user?

Comment: To clarrify, the reason I ask is that the windows Administrator user account is "special" in several ways. Among them being the MS has been trying to phase its use out and will probably remove it from Windows entirely one day. Even if you normally use a basic user account that cant elevates its own privileges, it's still better to create a dedicated administrative user and elevate to that... which also still works with "right click, run as admin" without necessitating batch files and runas shortcuts.

Answer (score 5):

I somehow managed to solve the issue by first running the command prompt as administrator using

```
runas /profile /savecred /user:administrator "cmd.exe"
```

put another batch file in `\windows\system32` folder to run the exe. and just type the name of that batch file.

Answer (score 5):

This is what worked for me

start cmd first then use it to start your other app

`runas /profile /user:ExlordPC\Exlord /savecred "cmd.exe /k C:\Users\Exlord\AppData\Local\NextVPN\NextVPN.exe"`

Comment: Can confirm, this works.

Comment: For me, this just opened a new command window.

Answer (score 3):

I just got bitten by this on a machine, now running Windows 10 version 1803 (as installed on 2018-06-18).

The solution (combined with the other answers here) for me was discovery (and reversion) of a change to my local PC's GPO.

- In the GPO snapin for `mmc.exe`
- Navigating to: `Local Computer Policy / Computer Configuration / Windows Settings / Security Settings / Local Policies / Security Options`
- There's a setting called 
  *"User Account Control: Admin Approval Mode for the Built-in Administrator account"*

Reverting that to what it calls the "Default" mode of *disabled* resolved the issue.

Possibly using an administrator account other than the built-in default might have worked too (untested).

Comment: I too found the local policy change is the way to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2):

```sh
runas /savecred /user:YourDomain\YourUser "cmd /c start /b mmc dsa.msc"
```

Comment: Could you provide some context for this answer?

Comment: @Burgi I don't know what you mean by context, but this did the trick for me, mainly the part around CMD "/c start /b". I'm on Windows 10 Enterprise 1803, under an AD Domain.

Comment: It first invokes a command prompt running in the context of another user with `runas`, then uses that to invoke the "START" command (another command prompt), further invoking the Microsoft Management Console specifically loading the DSA.MSC component. 

`CMD /C`: "Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates"; 
`START /B`: "Start application without creating a new window. The application has ^C handling ignored. Unless the application enables ^C processing, ^Break is the only way to interrupt the application."

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution 
create a batch file and put the following command in that
runas /profile /savecred /user:administrator "cmd.exe /C

eg.  runas /profile /savecred /user:administrator "cmd.exe /C D:\190914\SmartDB\smartdb.exe"

Save the batch file and run it.