# How to runas an application requiring elevation with a different user?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, uac, runas

I want to run `regedit` as a different user (i.e. to edit that user's registry entries).

So I've run `cmd` as an Administrator, then did

```
runas /profile /savecred /user:OtherUserName regedit
```

It asks for my password but after I type it in, I get

> RUNAS ERROR: Unable to run - regedit
>
> 740: The requested operation requires elevation.

I understand that `regedit` has to be run as an administrator, but I am running the command prompt as administrator. `OtherUserName` is an Administrator type user.

I'm guessing that even though I'm running for the current user as administrator, my acceptance of that doesn't pass over to `OtherUserName`.

But this is something I am able to do in Windows 7 Embedded.

I've tried:

- Group Policy - "Behavior of the elevation prompt for Administrators" - both `Prompt for Credentials` and `Elevate without Prompting`
- The upvoted answer here - [Windows 10 pro, after anniversary update I can't use "runas administrator shortcut" anymore](https://superuser.com/questions/1130065/windows-10-pro-after-anniversary-update-i-cant-use-runas-administrator-shortc) (`runas /profile /savecred /user:administrator "cmd.exe"` first, but with the current username instead of `administrator`).
  -

Comment: If you want to edit the users registry just check `HKEY_Users` or manually open the hive for the user.

Comment: Have you checked permissions for `regedit.exe`?

Comment: Try to add the parameter `/netonly` to the `runas` command.

Comment: Permissions for regedit.exe are fine, if I log in as `OtherUserName` I can run it fine. (They are also an administrator user). Tried `/netonly` but didn't work. As for `HKEY_Users` I need to put this into a .bat file / .reg file so that wouldn't be easy but I think I've managed to find a way around it - though I'm still puzzled why I can't `runas ... regedit`

Answer (score 0):

OK so I believe I've found a way around it, thanks to this page... https://www.itechtics.com/edit-registry-settings-other-users/

```
reg load HKU\OtherUserName C:\Users\OtherUserName \ntuser.dat
```

then

```
regedit
```

then there is a node

```
[HKEY_USERS\OtherUserName\...etc.]
```

in the registry settings.

It solves the problem for me, though it still doesn't answer the overall question of why I can't `runas` an application requiring elevated permissions...

Answer (score 0):

It is working when used with cmd:

```
runas /user:domain\login "cmd /c ^c:\windows\regedit.exe^"
```

[runas error 740: The requested operation requires elevation and cmd /c? - Windows Forum](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2232804-runas-error-740-the-requested-operation-requires-elevation-and-cmd-c)