# Can I open a virtual keyboard in a specific language in Windows?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

Is there a way to open a virtual windows keyboard in Russian while my language setting is Englisch or German?

Can I open a virtual keyboard by a script or any other shortcut in a different language as my current setting? According [this info here](https://thegeekpage.com/6-screen-keyboard-osk-opening-methods-windows-10/) I can use `osk` (powershell, cmd), but no chance to set the language.

---

I found an awkward solution. According to https://superuser.com/a/922767/72397 I can use a different user with the Russian locale.

Then I can use this user to start `osk`. Because of `740: The requested operation requires elevation` I need to work this workaround and fire another `cmd` first (see https://superuser.com/a/1134561/72397).

So `runas /profile /savecred /user:"RUSSIAN USER" "cmd /c start osk"` starts the osk with the locale of that specific user.

Edit 2: After some testing I have realized it is not possible to have an `OSK` different from my current locale, even if the `OSK` runs as a different user. As soon as I click somewhere on the `OSK` window it changes its keyboard layout to my locale.

The idea was to have one `OSK` running in Russian while I am working with a Germany keyboard layout.

So the best solution appears to use the `AutohotKey` solution, quickly change to Russian and then back.

---

Private remark, related to SO https://stackoverflow.com/q/74829525/356726

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a third-party tool.

You may use the free [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following example script will switch the system language to
a given installed language and start the on-screen keyboard.
Here <kbd>F11</kbd> will set the language to US-English, while
<kbd>F12</kbd> will set it to French-Standard.
More language codes may be found in the Microsoft article
[Language Codes](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Languages.htm).

```
F11::SetDefaultKeyboard(0x0409) ; english-US
F12::SetDefaultKeyboard(0x040c) ; french

SetDefaultKeyboard(LocaleID){
    Global
    SPI_SETDEFAULTINPUTLANG := 0x005A
    SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE := 2
    Lan := DllCall("LoadKeyboardLayout", "Str", Format("{:08x}", LocaleID), "Int", 0)
    VarSetCapacity(Lan%LocaleID%, 4, 0)
    NumPut(LocaleID, Lan%LocaleID%)
    DllCall("SystemParametersInfo", "UInt", SPI_SETDEFAULTINPUTLANG, "UInt", 0, "UPtr", &Lan%LocaleID%, "UInt", SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE)
    WinGet, windows, List
    Loop %windows% {
        PostMessage 0x50, 0, %Lan%, , % "ahk_id " windows%A_Index%
    }
    Sleep, 100
    Run, C:\Windows\System32\osk.exe
}
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on
the green H icon in the traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login,
place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)

Comment: Thanks, will check that one. Question, would I need to reset to my original keyboard after running that script, or are the changes only within the scope  of `SetDefaultKeyboard`?

Comment: Thanks, works fine, as assumed changes Keyboard globally. So I need to get a bit into detail and reset the keyboard settings after OSK is opened. I will accept your answer in 1-2 days, only curious if someone else responds.

Comment: Added some more findings to the original question. Thanks for your help!